# How to Create a Vinyl Plastic Toy Shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

How can I make one of the vinyl toy plastic material like this?

[image: example of a plastic shader in C4D/Octane Render]

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Njl5hLmGs0

Comment: Start with a Diffuse BSDF Shader for the base colour and a Mix Shader with a Glossy Shader. Pay attention to the Roughness setting on the Glossy Shader. Play around with that simple Node setup and come back if you have any specific questions. If you are more adventurous just use a Principled BSDF Shader and play with the Metal and roughness.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Creating a Plastic Material in Blender Cycles

---

So I've been through the linked **[C4D tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Njl5hLmGs0)** and have adapted (where possible) the Octane setup that EJ uses to create the materials for the Apple caricature model. This is the result of my Cycles node setup:

[image: Main Render Result]

[image: Close-up Render Results]

Essentially, as EJ states, the plastic appearance of the material revolves around the subtle grungy roughness and bump texture applied to the surface. Although he uses a custom finger-prints grunge map to create a more worn surface texture, I have used a distorted *Noise Texture* node to achieve a similar, procedural effect.  Below is my node-setup for the material:

[image: Plastic Node setup]

To begin, a *Principled BSDF* shader is added and connected to the *Material Output node*, and a desirable colour is chosen. From this, the first *Noise Texture* is thrown through a *Color Ramp* node and overlaid over a Roughness value, defined with the *Value* node. The purpose of this is to allow you to tweak the overall roughness of the plastic material and have it respond normally, yet with the texture intensity reacting procedurally on top. It's a subtle effect, but really goes a long way in adding realism (even if the even result is a stylized character!).

The second *Noise Texture* generates a much more defined and uniform pattern that is a lot smaller, and helps to add the subtle surface bumps on the plastic (shown in the close-up images) that would be created in the real world forming process. This texture is connected to a *Bump* node and then to the *Normal* input of the original *Principled BSDF* shader.

---

And that's about it! It's a fairly simple shader, however the combinations of nodes used, as well as the flexibility of the *Principled BSDF* shader, allow for different layered variations to be easily created and adapted to your needs. I've also uploaded my *.blend file* which you can download and play about with.

[image]

Comment: There looks to be some diffuse speckle/noise in the original? Maybe just the result of low-res render of the bump, though...

Comment: @Robin Betts , certainly there doesn't seem to be any added in the original tutorial. I believe it's either due to the original render being a lower-res screenshot in the question (as you mentioned) or because the scaling of the bump texture is less fine :)