# Lego Surface Imperfections?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm attempting to recreate tiny brick imperfections similar to the Lego Movie, but I'm having a hard time finding realistic textures to accomplish this effect.

[image]

Generating a mix of noise textures and scratches comes close, but still looks a bit too artificial. Any idea what kind of texture I'd need to create/find to reproduce something like this?

Answer (score 1):

For the answer, you can use this (as shown):

[image]

[How to Create a Vinyl Plastic Toy Shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116195/how-to-create-a-vinyl-plastic-toy-shader)

### Just try to pay attention to detail!

Answer (score 0):

You may try the "Polypropylene Plastic" from textures.com. Attached Link: https://www.textures.com/download/pbr0149/133184

You just have to plug the textures to your BSDF. You may mix the "...albedo" texture with an RGB node. So you can adjust your wanted color.